# Composable – adding isVisible argument to every component

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My work colleague, for most newly designed Compose component adds the `isVisible` argument to control visibility, like below:

```
@Composable
fun SomeComponent(
   label: String,
   isVisible: Boolean = true
) {
  if (!isVisible) return;
  Text(text = label)
}
```

His stance is - he prefers it that way. I think he's just used to what pre-Compose world of views in Android looked like (when all views had `isVisible` control).

Imho it's more readable when handled by external code, like

```
if (isModeEnabled) {
   SomeComponent(label = "Mode enabled")
}
```

Is there any argument (other than style/personal preference), say performance or clean code rule, that would speak for my approach? It strikes me even more because it is a function, so in a non-compose world that would looks plain stupid to write:

```
fun sendMessage(
   email: String,
   body: String,
   shouldSend: Boolean = true)
) {
  if (shouldSend) return;
  …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two arguments:

1. With conditions, you can make use of `if - else if - else` statement:

   ```
   if (A && B && C)
       Component1()
   else if (A)
       Component2()
   else
       Component3()
   ```

   is arguably more readable and less error prone than:

   ```
   Component1(isVisible = A && B && C)
   Component2(isVisible = A && (!B || !C))
   Component3(isVisible = !A)
   ```
2. The approach with `isVisible` can lead to unnecessary state reads and recompositions:

   ```
   val state by viewModel.someState.collectAsState()

   // here, state is only read when `showEmptyScreen == false`, so as long as
   // we are showing empty screen, changes to state won't lead to recomposition
   if (showEmptyScreen)
       EmptyScreen()
   else 
       Content(state = state)

   // here, state is read always, so every change to state will lead to recomposition
   // even when EmptyScreen is shown and we don't care about state
   EmptyScreen(isVisible = showEmptyScreen)
   Content(state = state, isVisible = !showEmptyScreen)
   ```

Comment: Thanks Jan. I agree with both points. Now I'm thinking that even without considering multiple types of components, a single component that will take arguments like `isVisible` and `state` will be recomposed too often. For isVisible being false, no updates to state should result in recompose. Thanks for input again! I appreciate it.